# cross compile on mac for windows

Tags: compilation, g++, cross-platform, fltk

I'm building a project using FLTK in c++ on a 2012 MacBook pro running Mac OSX 10.8.5 and compiling using i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 from the command line.

Ideally I would like to cross compile for windows without learning VS in windows, installing all the dependencies etc. so am interested in cross compiling for windows from mac.

I found this http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php?id=start and downloaded a package which automatically installed. I then downloaded the example source code to see if it worked and it just gave me a bunch of errors.

Looking at the make file it refers to directories I simply don't have. For instance the supplied make file reads

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
#                                                                              *
# C + +    H E L L O W O R L D    F O R    M I N G W 3 2    O N    M A C O S X *
#                                                                            *
#   Updated for Release 2                                                    *
#                                                                              *
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

TOOL_DIR := /usr/local/i386-mingw32-3.4.5/bin

SOURCES := hello_world.cpp

OBJECTS_DIR := objects

EXECUTABLE := hello_world_in_cpp.exe

ALL_OBJECT_FILES := $(patsubst %, $(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))

all:$(OBJECTS_DIR) $(EXECUTABLE)

#--- Make object dir
$(OBJECTS_DIR):
    mkdir $(OBJECTS_DIR)

#--- C++ compile : use gcc
$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.cpp.o:%.cpp
    $(TOOL_DIR)/i386-mingw32-gcc -c $< -o $@

#--- C++ link : use g++
$(EXECUTABLE):$(ALL_OBJECT_FILES)
    $(TOOL_DIR)/i386-mingw32-g++ $< -o $@
    $(TOOL_DIR)/i386-mingw32-strip --strip-all $@

clean:
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE)
    rm -Rf $(OBJECTS_DIR)/
```

Looking at what has arrived in my /usr/ directory I have (amongst others)

```
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0-qt-4.8.4-for-mingw32 
    contents.txt
    win32-gcc/
        bin/
            i586-mingw32-g++
            i586-mingw32-gcc
        i586-mingw32/
            bin/
                g++
                gcc
    win32-qt/
```

By trial and error I simply ran from the command line

```
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.0-qt-4.8.4-for-mingw32/win32-gcc/bin/i586-mingw32-g++ hello_world.cpp
```

the bundled sample source code and that does at least compile and produces 'a.exe'.

I assume that is what I should be doing? But am not sure.

Next I need to compile my FLTK project. By compiling as I normally would but replacing g++ with /usr/local/gcc-4.8.0-qt-4.8.4-for-mingw32/win32-gcc/bin/i586-mingw32-g++

To do this I use the fltk-config script which essentially  is equiavlent to compiling with the command

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/FL/images -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT
```

/usr/local/lib/libfltk_images.a /usr/local/lib/libfltk_png.a -lz /usr/local/lib/libfltk_jpeg.a /usr/local/lib/libfltk_gl.a -framework AGL -framework OpenGL -framework ApplicationServices /usr/local/lib/libfltk_forms.a /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a -lpthread -framework Cocoa main.cpp -o go

I also link to some static .a libraries in addition to this above.

However, when I do the above with the i586-mingw32-g++ compiler I find the following errors and don't know how I would get round them (if indeed that is possible)

```
i586-mingw32-g++: error: AGL: No such file or directory
i586-mingw32-g++: error: OpenGL: No such file or directory
i586-mingw32-g++: error: ApplicationServices: No such file or directory
i586-mingw32-g++: error: Cocoa: No such file or directory
i586-mingw32-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’
i586-mingw32-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’
i586-mingw32-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’
i586-mingw32-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: AGL, Cocoa and `-framework` are Mac specific libraries and compiler options respectively - if you need those things in your code it won't be able to compile for windows

Comment: In fact I would believe that all those libraries you are trying to link have been compiled with your native Mac compiler and won't be compatible with Windows